# Unable to switch back to full (desktop) chat site in IE

Tags: bug, chat

In IE, if I click the "Mobile" link in the footer in chat, I can't switch back to the Desktop version.

This morning I performed my regular routine of logging in to Stack Overflow and immediately heading to chat. However, my chat loaded in the mobile version of the site rather than the main desktop site. (How this happened I am not sure, but that's an issue for another day.)

To switch back to the mobile site I was instructed to hit the hamburger menu icon and then press "full site", but clicking the hamburger menu didn't do anything, in fact, none of the buttons do anything.

@Makyen replicated this issue on IE and also couldn't switch back. Eventually, after some good digging around they found that you could open up the console window (F12) and run this:

```
CHAT.switchMobile('off');
```

this worked but was very difficult to find as it wasn't documented anywhere.

Comment: You clicked the mobile link from IE? You're braver than I thought!

Comment: yeah.. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306801/having-difficulty-placing-bounty-on-a-question) is another question about SO/SE issues in IE and according to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306801/having-difficulty-placing-bounty-on-a-question#comment997466_306801) it would probably be "6 to 8 weeks". I would avoid IE at this point

Comment: I've started avoiding IE ages ago. It's gotten to the point where I will cross the street if I see IE walking down the sidewalk. Doing fine so far.

Comment: @TravisJ I didn't click the link it loaded like that

Comment: People still use IE? I thought everyone knew it was to be avoided like the plague. Although Edge is surprisingly not that bad once you get to windows 10.

Comment: @DavyM: It's very common in certain industries, things like lab PCs that have never even seen a network that extends out of the building (or even the room) but need to expose "web" apps, come with IE and so IE it shall remain. Also when working through something like Citrix you tend to see it a lot, again probably due to its native nature. Out in the hobbyist/home web surfing world, though, I'm sure it's different.

Comment: "Hamburger menu icon" glorious.

Comment: @RickAstley That's the actual name of the menu icon.

Comment: @DavyM I find myself using IE from time to time as an owner of a Windows RT device.